# Cant Find the Template to Create a Visual C++ Windows Service in VS 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, service

My Visual Studio 2015 don't have template for Windows Service in Visual C++.
Workaround is to create ATL project with service type, but it doesn't make sense to have templates for VB and VC# and not for VisualC++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such template for VC++ services.

Simple templates, samples and frameworks can be found on Codeproject and other public locations:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/781449/A-Simple-Cplusplus-Class-Framework-for-Services
- http://www.naughter.com/serv.html

Comment: Can't believe! Actually Microsoft has to create system services for Windows and .NET isn't as fast enough as fast is c++.

Comment: And there is no problem to create your own service. I always use the PJ Naughter code. I wouldn't use a skeleton that just implements the base "simple" stuff. An dI have to confess that I don't like all those wizards at all. ;)